Output Paragraph via view from Layout Builder
I have a paragraph that references users (like a directory) attached to a node. I have created a view that works just fine by assigning the view block to the node and its spits out the results. However, when I try to do the same via Layout Builder (meaning I select the view block from Layout Builder), I don't have any results. Do I need to configure the view different if I'm assigning it from Layout Builder? I'm in Drupal 9. Thanks!

Note, Drupal 9 is out-of-support so you really should update to a supported release of Drupal ASAP. It would probably be helpful for anyone answering if you provided more details about how you configured the view block display including, and specifically, Contextual Filters (arguments).
